# Wrap multiple list items in a new tag ('ul'/'ol') using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, list, beautifulsoup

Hopefully this is simple -- I have several paragraphs. With Beautiful Soup I'm converting them to lists using `link.parent.name = 'li'` but I'd appreciate it if anyone could let me know how I can wrap the entire created list of multiple li tags in new `<ul> </ul>` tags?.

As there will be multiple separate lists on a given page, I'd like to be able to select all the siblings if possible and wrap them all in the new tag.

So

```
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>

<li>2</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>2</li>

<li>3</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>3</li>
```

will look like

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>2</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>3</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can't you use normal `for`-loop and add it as normal text - without using `BeautifulSoup` ? All what you have is a string so using string functions could be simpler. Eventually if you want to generate HTML file you can use Jinja2 to create template which can also use `for`-loops and it works with strings.

Comment: BTW: using `BeautifulSoup` I would first create `<ul>` and then put 3 `<li>` inside this `<ul>`, and later I would repeat it for other `<ul>`. So it would need `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlText = '''
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>

<li>2</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>2</li>

<li>3</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>3</li>
'''

paragraphs = htmlText.split('\n\n')   # splits paragraph whenever there is an empty new line

for paragraph in paragraphs:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(paragraph)
    lis = soup.find_all('li')
    ul = soup.new_tag('ul')

    for li in lis:
        ul.append(li)

    print(ul)
```

Returns:

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul>
<ul><li>2</li><li>2</li><li>2</li></ul>
<ul><li>3</li><li>3</li><li>3</li></ul>
```

The most important part would be defining the `paragraphs` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is interesting - I'm actually making a plugin for different input files so I can't define the paragraphs variable exactly. Is there a way to just search for all the siblings of the list item and wrapping that in a ul? Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes you can [find siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) and then append to a new `ul` the same way as above. You can probably just find the first `li` then find the next siblings from there.